# Questions in the official Spring documentation

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

Here is an example from the [official documentation (You need to scroll down a little)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.property-population)：

```
class Person {

  private final @Id Long id;                                                
  private final String firstname, lastname;                                 
  private final LocalDate birthday;
  private final int age; 

  private String comment;                                                   
  private @AccessType(Type.PROPERTY) String remarks;                        

  static Person of(String firstname, String lastname, LocalDate birthday) { 

    return new Person(null, firstname, lastname, birthday,
      Period.between(birthday, LocalDate.now()).getYears());
  }

  Person(Long id, String firstname, String lastname, LocalDate birthday, int age) { 

    this.id = id;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.birthday = birthday;
    this.age = age;
  }

  Person withId(Long id) {                                                  
    return new Person(id, this.firstname, this.lastname, this.birthday);
  }

  void setRemarks(String remarks) {                                         
    this.remarks = remarks;
  }
}
```

I have a few questions about this.

1. `Person withId(Long id)` Does the referenced construction function **not exist** in the example?
2. `Person withId(Long id)`  There is a description in the official documentation ："The same pattern is usually applied for other properties that are store managed but might have to be changed for persistence operations". Can I understand it this way: After successfully saving the instance, `WithOutIdPerson` can be used for other field changes and saved again, and `SavedPerson` can be used for other upper level operations?
3. Why is the last step of the factory `of ()` called in the example??

Thank you~

Comment: What is `SavedPerson` you are referring to in (2)? What is the example you are referring to in (3)?

Comment: (2) ```SavedPerson``` is an entity that has been saved to the repository and carries an ID identifier.  ```WithOutIdPerson```Is a new entity that is not saved to the repository and has no ID identifier.     (3) The example is **Example.56** in the official document labeled  **6th**  small step of color.  The question I want to ask is why the last step calls of() factory method.  thank you~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Question 1

> `Person withId(Long id)` Does the referenced construction function not exist in the example?

That is probably a bug in the documentation, it should look like this:

```
Person withId(Long id) {                                                  
    return new Person(id, this.firstname, this.lastname, this.birthday, this.age);
}
```

#### Question 2

> After successfully saving the instance, `WithOutIdPerson` can be used for other field changes and saved again, and `SavedPerson` can be used for other upper level operations?

If I understand you correct you are wondering if this would work:

```
Person p = Person.of( "Peter", "Parker", someDate);
Person saved  = personRepository.save(p);
Person savedAgain = personRepository.save(p);
```

**If** the id attribute of `Person` is set by the database and it is an immutable attribute (it has a *wither* as given in the example) then `p` and `saved` (and `savedAgain`) are distinct entities and the two `save` operations result in two rows being stored in the database and `saved` and `savedAgain` having distinct ids and `p` has still id equal to `null`.

#### Question 3

> Why is the last step of the factory `of()` called in the example?

Actually, `of()` isn't called at all in the example code.
Why a factory method is recommended over overloaded constructors is explained in note number (6) of the code:

> The class exposes a factory method and a constructor for object creation. The core idea here is to use factory methods instead of additional constructors to avoid the need for constructor disambiguation through @PersistenceConstructor. Instead, defaulting of properties is handled within the factory method.

Without the factory you would have two constructors and would need to [use `@PersistenceConstructor` on one in order to tell Spring Data which one to use for instance creation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.object-creation).

Comment: Use ```personRepository.findById(ID id)``` to return a ```Person``` instance, so will the first call the ```of()``` factory method to build the instance?  thanks~